# how to use the optimizer and profiler in visual studio

Tags: c, visual-studio

can someone show me how to run the visual studio (2010) profiler tool and optimizer on my program?
Thanks

Comment: This question has only one of two possible answers, yes or no.  Pick one.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can look for [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182372.aspx) sample